# The length of the sequence concatenated two sequences

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, foundations

Let $\alpha$ be a finite sequence, and $|\alpha|$ be the length of $\alpha$.

Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ be two finite sequences. Prove that $|\alpha_1 \alpha_2| = |\alpha_1 |+|\alpha_2|$. Where $\alpha_1 \alpha_2$ is just the concatenation of the sequences $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

This looks  very obvious. But I do not know what to do if I want to deal with it more precisely.

Comment: Do you mean sequence or set?

Comment: @TheD0ubleT $\alpha, \alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are all sequences.

Comment: If you want to do this very formally, then we should start by asking what is your formal definition of sequence and concatenation. Then I suspect that your definition of concatenation will already contain the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MichalAdamaszek !!